# Clonezilla of a dualboot of XP and Linux to a SSD. Startup says: Grub:

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, grub, clonezilla

I have an 10 years old HP laptop with an excellent(stunning) lcd and a lot of good software for car analyze/parts along with a lot of Python software.  Dual boot with XP SP2 and a Linux version.

To extend the lifetime of this remarkable tool :) yes, still really good, I have installed a new battery pack, new power supply, new 3V litium battery AND a new SSD of 120GB.

I booted up the clonezilla cd and made a copy of the harddisk 80GB to the SSD 120GB.

When I installed the SSD and booted it prompts immediately with grub.

Anyone familiar with a solution to this problem? 
I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Boot loaders/managers for any OS on MBR style disks are loaded by:

1) MBR

2) PBR on active partition

You used Clonezilla for disk/partition copying. Seems partition addresses in MBR and/or PBR are not the same as on original disk.

You should fix booting in this order:

1) **Fix boot for Windows XP** - write new Windows XP code in MBR and PBR on active partition (and check that ntldr and boot.ini are on active partition).

2) [Fix GRUB after installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: Any good place to learn about boot.ini and modyfing MBR and PBR? It boot automatic in Linux if not any active selection of windows. Could it be it load Linux in the first place? Will this modify the fix?

Comment: MBR and PBR are modified using bootsect.exe command in Vista and later, fixmbr and fixboot in XP, see also https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html - dual-boot repair tool(can fix XP boot) and https://www.boyans.net/ArcPaths/ArcPaths.htm - ARC path utility for displaying proper boot path used in "boot.ini".

Comment: Once GRUB is in control of the booting you should change boot order (Linux, Windows) editing GRUB configuration.